# Можно ли с помощью функции is_dir в php проверить является ли файл директорией, включая в путь название диска?

Tags: php

Я пишу не большую программку на php по работе с файлами. При написании столкнулся с такой проблемой: папки, которые находятся по относительному пути (Пример: "./fold1/auto/www") is_dir видит и возвращает true, но мне нужно, чтобы папки обрабатывались по абсолютному пути (например: "C:\Users\adm\Desktop\fold"). Не смотря на то, что папка по такому пути существует is_dir возвращает false. Как я могу заставить эту функцию корректно обрабатывать абсолютные пути? Может есть какая-то альтернатива этой функции? Буду признателен за ответ.

Comment: а так - `$isDir = is_dir(addslashes("C:\Users\adm\Desktop\fold"));`?

Comment: Попробуйте изменить обратный слеш на обычный -  `C:/Users/adm/Desktop/fold`

Comment: А этот путь-то виден вообще вебсерверу? Так как сервер никсовый со слешами, а проверка пути от виндов с обратными слешами.

Comment: Попробовал использовать addslashes. Теперь в строке пути слетела кодировка. У меня рассматривается такой случай, что папки могу называться русскими символами. Из-за этого возникали проблемы с кодировкой, которые я решил так: iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1251');. Но если использовать  addslashes, то строка в которой была кириллица выглядит примерно так: "C\\Users\\??????\\fold"

Comment: Обратные слеши тоже к сожалению не помогают

Comment: Сервер вряд ли будет иметь доступ к директориям вне своего корня (обычно так делается из соображений безопасности), и поэтому может возвращать false в таких случаях.

Comment: `is_dir(realpath("./fold1/auto/www"))` так работает? папку с примера взял, ищите существующую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Можно, но не стоит!**

Посмотри внимательно на классы

**SplFileInfo**
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileinfo.php

**DirectoryIterator**
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php

Всё-же не в 2000ых живём, и есть гораздо более правильные решения.

Не допускающие такие случаи когда директория является Симлинком или VirtualDevice. Меньше косяков в коде получишь на выходе.